# AFNetworking GET request with query is not working

Tags: ios, afnetworking

this is always error with -1004 ( could not connect to server )
but the request in browser is working fine.
what's wrong with my code?

```
(url : "http://localhost:3000/v1/voice/version?appname=wevoice")


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:@"http://localhost:3000/v1/voice/version"
  parameters:@{ @"appname": @"wevoice" }
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
}
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: `localhost` refers to the machine the app is running on. Are you running this on an iOS device or in the simulator? What device are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the property `baseURL` on your request manager. Here is an example:

```
self.requestManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:http://localhost:3000];
```

Later, in your concrete GET message to the manager, you'll only pass the relative URL path:

```
[self.requestManager GET:@"/v1/voice/version"
  parameters:@{ @"appname": @"wevoice" }
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
}
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

And keep in mind, that, if you want to send your paramters as JSON, you'll need a request serializer:

```
self.requestManager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: Your error is NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost (-1004) so are you a 100% sure that the server is running and connectable from your simulator (localhost will not probably work on the device)

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dic setObject:@"wevoice" forKey:@"appname"];

[manager GET:@"http://localhost:3000/v1/voice/version"
  parameters:dic
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

You can try this.May be the way you add Parameter is wrong.

Comment: yes it's same error. my request doesn't reach localhost server.

Comment: @breaklee I guess is your local server's problem.You need check your server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. Hope it helps.

```
+ (void)getRequestWithURLStringWithSuccess:(void(^)(id object))successBlock andFail:(void(^)(NSString *errorMessage))failBlock {

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/v1/voice/version"]];

NSString *urlString = @"/version";

[manager GET:urlString parameters:@{ @"appname": @"wevoice" } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

 }];
```

}